# Ensure that Vuex state is loaded before render component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a `add-user.vue` component. It is my template for adding a new user and editing a existing user. So on page load I check if route has a `id`, if so I load a user from a state array to edit it. My issue is that `user` is undefined because the state array `users` is empty. How can I ensure that my user object isn't undefined. It does load sometimes but on refresh it doesn't. I thought I had it covered but nope. This is my setup. What am I missing here?

Store

```
state: {
  users: []
},

getters: {
  users: state =>
    _.keyBy(state.users.filter(user => user.deleted === false), 'id')
},

actions: {
  fetchUsers({
    commit
  }) {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3000/users')
      .then(response => {
        commit('setUsers', response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error:', error);
      });
  }
}
```

In my `add-user.vue` component I have the following in the `data()` `computed:{}` and  `created()`

```
data() {
  return {
    user: {
      id: undefined,
      name: undefined,
      gender: undefined
    }
  };
},

computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['users'])
},

created() {
  if (this.$route.params.userId === undefined) {
    this.user.id = uuid();
    ...
  } else {
    this.user = this.users[this.$route.params.userId];
  }
}
```

Template

```
<template>
  <div class="add-user" v-if="user"></div>
</template>
```

My `User.vue` I have the following setup, where I init the fetch of users on `created()`

```
<template>
  <main class="main">
    <AddUser/>
    <UserList/>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import AddUser from '@/components/add-user.vue';
import UserList from '@/components/user-list.vue';

export default {
    name: 'User',

    components: {
        AddUser,
        UserList
    },

    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsers');
    }
};
</script>
```

I have tried this. When saving in my editor it works but not on refresh. The `dispatch().then()` run before the `mutation` setting the users does.

```
created() {
  if (this.$route.params.userId === undefined) {
    this.user.id = uuid();
    ...
  } else {
    if (this.users.length > 0) {
                this.user = this.users[this.$route.params.userId];
            } else {
                this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsers').then(() => {
                    this.user = this.users[this.$route.params.userId];
                });
            }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's likely that the computed value is not yet mapped in `created` hook. try using `this.$store.getters.users` in `created` or move ur codes into `mounted` hook

Comment: @JacobGoh from my understanding having the `getters` in created makes no difference, as it is reactive. When the `fetchUsers` is done the getters will have value.

Comment: I would suggest that you always anticipate that the user is not loaded - so first check if it is in the store. If yes - then simply use it. Otherwise dispatch an AJAX request to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case it was just going back and forth to the same vue instance. Solved it by adding `:key="some-unique-key"`, so it looks like this.

```
<template>
  <main class="main">

    <AddUser :key="$route.params.userId"/>

    <UserList/>

  </main>
</template>
```

Answer (score 15):

I would use `beforeRouteEnter` in `User.vue` so that the component is not initialized before the data is loaded.
(Assuming you are using `vue-router`)

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    if (store.state.users.length === 0) {
        store.dispatch(fetchUsers)
        .then(next);
    }
},
```

You'll need to
`import store from 'path/to/your/store'`
because `this.$store` is not available until the component is initialized.

Answer (score 6):

Although this solved, but I will answer for future comers. You may issue the `dispatch` beforehand as Shu suggested, or you may still dispatch on same component `mounted` hook, but use some state variable to track the progress:

```
data:{
    ...
    loading:false,
    ...
},
...
mounted(){
this.loading = true,
this.$store
  .dispatch('fetchUsers')
  .finally(() => (this.loading=false));
}
```

Then in your template you use this `loading` state variable to either render the page or to render some spinner or progress bar:

```
<template>
    <div class='main' v-if="!loading">
        ...all old template goes her
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" v-else>
        Loading...
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .overlay {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      z-index: 10;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
</style>
```