# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'shipperid' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I know this has been asked before but nothing seems to match my problem. I can't figure out what is going on.

Error

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'shipperid' of undefined"

I'm retrieving the data from an API as a state (vuex) not local data.

```
  <template>
    <div>Hello
      <div>{{allBatches[0].shipperid}}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
      import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
      export default {
        name: "batching",
        components: {},
        props: {},
        data: function() {
          return {};
        },
        computed: {
          ...mapGetters(["allBatches"])
        },
        methods: {
          ...mapActions(["fetchBatches"])
        },
        created() {
          this.fetchBatches();
        }
      };
  </script>
```

The data is coming, but the error is bugging me.

Also, if I edit it, this error happens. I kind of understand what they want me to do, but I don't think I know how. The defaultvalue is coming from the reusable component. (All added to the sandbox) I'd appreciate any help

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "defaultvalue"

Here is a minimal copy of my system in a **[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-8etxh)**

Comment: allBatches is empty when the component renders, it gets data after fetchBatches finishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add `v-if` condition in your template due to fact that when your component is created/mounted, you will not have any detail in vuex's `allBatches` getters if the API is still running in background.

So modify your template with,

```
 <div>Hello
     <div v-if="allBatches">{{allBatches[0].shipperid}}</div>
 </div>
```

whenever the API call will complete, `allBatches` will be changed & due to reactivity it will re-render the html with changes of `allBatches`.

Comment: Close. Since the array `allBatches` in the provided example is initiated with the store, it can still throw the error because even an empty array's truthiness is `true`. If you choose the condition `v-if="allBatches[0]"` it checks if the accessed item is actually present. For safety you can go with `allBatches && allBatches[0]`, although here that wouldn't be neccessary

Comment: @CGundlach Yeah, you're right. I noticed that and used it as you described and it worked. However, it is kind of bloaty that I have to add that v-if to every single instance of data call I am populating from the API...I wonder if there is a cleaner solution for this. Regardless, it is an answer nonetheless. So I thank you Aniket

Comment: I suppose you wouldn't be able to help me out with the second error I listed, would you? The one that happens when the field is edited and the defaultvalue that is binded is mutated. It's ok if you don't. I don't mean to push

Comment: @LOTUSMS You can make sure that your vuex data is loaded before component creation by having `beforeRouteEnter` method. [Reference stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51819175/5518973). But this again depends if you are using vue-router or not

Comment: @AniketPawar As a simpler solution I added the v-if at the highest scope in the vue file. One instance covered all of them.

Comment: @LOTUSMS: If you have multiple batches (Not clear from the example, but you're using an array so I guess that's the case) you can also use `v-for="item in array" :key="item.uniqueIdentifier"`. This won't show an error if the array is empty. If it's not an actual array, your solution is as good as any.

Comment: @LotusMS regarding the second error... I usually don't use Vue with JS, so I'm not sure how to write it there, but in my Typescript components I usually have a getter and a setter for the data. The getter gets the data from the props or the store, while the setter will call a mutation on the store.

Comment: @CGundlach Yeah I have my getters and setters in place in my vuex store setup. I think the link to the codesandbox I sent in the question has that included.

Comment: @LOTUSMS Yeah, you're using Store getter and setters, but not in the InputText component. In that you're modifying the prop directly, which Vue does not like. See [this page](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) in the vue docs on how to mutate values passed to a child component properly.

Comment: @LOTUSMS Personally, I usually don't pass data retrieved from the store to a component and instead have getters and mutations for most store data, so I can just e.g. pass the ID of an item to a component and the component retrieves and mutates the item from the store itself. A bit more verbose, but a lot cleaner imho.